# Error : "requestFeature must be called before adding content"

Tags: android, tabs, titlebar

This code giving me error : "requestFeature() must be called before adding content". Now i have tried calling requestFeature before "setContent" and after "setContent" still getting error. Any guess :

```
public class Support extends TabActivity {

private ImageView mSpinnerImage = null;
private Animation mAnimation = null;
private Button button = null;
private TextView synctitle = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        /*Titlebar + Button*/
        setContentView(R.layout.support);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
        button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.syncbutton);
        mSpinnerImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spinner_view);
        mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_animation);
        synctitle  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.synctitele);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 mSpinnerImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 synctitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 mSpinnerImage.setAnimation(mAnimation);
                 mSpinnerImage.startAnimation(mAnimation);
            }
        });
        /*Titlebar + Button ends*/

        /*Tabs*/
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TestListView.class);
        spec = tabHost  .newTabSpec("some_things")
                        .setIndicator("Info")
                        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TestListView.class);
        spec = tabHost  .newTabSpec("top_things")
                        .setIndicator("Log")
                        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 85;
        /*Tabs ends*/
}
```

}

Comment: Try it before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); Just a guess but since a tab is hosted within an activity, the super call may be creating some content.

Comment: As mentioned tried both vice versa "before and after" but nothing works

Comment: The comment from NigelK suggested that you call `requestWindowFeature()` **before calling `super.onCreate()`**, not before calling `setContentView()`.

Comment: David...Tried that too...but no luck....